# custom error page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-error-pages

I have web application in asp.net.
I have to implement custom error page.
Means if any eror occurs(runtime).
I have to display exception and stacktrace on errorpage.aspx
shall i handle from master page or on page level and how.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error_Page.aspx"></customErrors>
```

Comment: If you set custom errors to Off it'll just show you the error and stacktrace in the asp default exception page. Don't know if that'll do it for you?

Comment: i have to write details and stack trace about error on ErrorPage.aspx from users point of view

Answer (score 4):

You can handle it in global.asax :

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Exception ex = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Error;
   //Use here
   System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ClearError();
   //Write custom error page in response
   System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(customErrorPageContent);
   System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 500;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please do not use Redirection as a means of displaying error messages, because it breaks HTTP. In case of an error, it makes sense for the server to return an appropriate 4xx or 5xx response, and not a 301 Redirection to a 200 OK response. I don't know why Microsoft added this option to ASP.NET's Custom Error Page feature, but fortunately you don't need to use it.

I recommend using IIS Manager to generate your web.config file for you. As for handling the error, open your `Global.asax.cs` file and add a method for `Application_Error`, then call `Server.GetLastError()` from within.

Comment: Dai  i have to write details and stack trace about error on ErrorPage.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) dll for displaying your error with nice UI. You can maintain log using this DLL.

Answer (score 1):

In the Global.asax

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{    
    Session["error"] = Server.GetLastError().InnerException; 
}
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{      
    Session["error"] = null;
}
```

In the Error_Page Page_Load event

```
if (Session["error"] != null)
{
    // You have the error, do what you want
}
```

Comment: This won't work as the Session object is not available when the Application_Error event is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the error using Server.GetLastError;

```
var exception = Server.GetLastError();
  if (exception != null)
    {
       //Display Information here
    }
```

For more information : [HttpServerUtility.GetLastError Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.getlasterror.aspx)

Comment: is this efficient way..means i have to place above on every page..should i handle any errors on master page only..